# About ISBN Code

Tags: coding-theory

In Raymond Hill's book "A First Course in Coding Theory" there exixts the following question and its answer.

**Question:** The ISBN $0-02-32\blacksquare \blacksquare 80-0$ has been received with smudges. What is the missing digits?

**Answer:** The number is $00232xy80,$ where we see that
each of $x,y$ is $0,8$ or $9.$ For the number to be an ISBN, we require $%
6x+7y=7,$ i.e. $y=1+7x.$ Now $x=0\Rightarrow y=$ $1;x=8\Rightarrow
y=2;x=9\Rightarrow y=9.$ So $x=y=9.$

**My Solution:** It is known that the ISBN code satisfies the linear equation
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i=1}^{10}ix_{i} &=&1\cdot 0+2\cdot 0+3\cdot 2+4\cdot 3+5\cdot
2+6x+7y+8\cdot 8+9\cdot 0+10\cdot 0 \\
&=&6x+7y+4\equiv 0(\bmod\text{ }11).
\end{eqnarray*}

Thus, we have the following solutions to the resulting linear equation:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
x & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\ \hline
y & 1 & 8 & 4 & 0 & 7 & 3 & 10 & 6 & 2 & 9 \\ \hline
\end{array}%
\end{equation*}
Apart from $x=y=9,$ there are nine more solutions given in the table above to the linear equation. What point am I missing here? My question is that "Why each of $x,y$ is $0,8$ or $9$ ? Any help will be appeciated!

Answer (score 2):

The answer says "we can see" the missing digits are $0, 8,$ or $9$.  Look at the original smudges in the book and see if you can distingulsh that!  I am guessing your `\blacksquare` rendition is not an accurate  copy the smudges.

[image: smudges]

The top bits of those two digits are not smudged.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I changed the question without realizing the detail. I am convinced. Many thanks!